# get exact process name with ps

Tags: android, linux, ps

When an Android app has many processes, how can I find the exact one by name?
For example, an app has three processes:

```
com.aaa.bb
com.aaa.bb:push
com.aaa.bb:backup
```

I try to use `ps` command, because `pgrep` is not available on my phone.

```
ps com.aaa.bb <---- this works fine, prints the process
ps com.aaa.bb:push  <---- this doesn't work, prints nothing
```

How can I find the process by its full name?